# Is the anonymous function inside a callback invoked using iife?

Tags: javascript, callback

I am trying to understand how an anonymous function inside of a callback function is invoked.
For example:

```
 const callbackExample = function(param, callback) {
        console.log('This is an example of a callback function');
        callback(param);
    };

    callbackExample('What', function(param) {
        console.log(param);
    })
```

My question is how does a anonymous function get invoked?  If I substitute the callback to equal the anonymous function below.
Is the callback being substituted for the anonymous function.

```
Does the callback === function(param) { console.log(param) }

What I mean is I cannot invoke the function like this.
function() { console.log('Not') } ();
```

There are only three ways to declare and invoke a function.
assign a anonymous function a name: function expression
give a function a name:  function declaration
Immediate Invocation function express

My theory is when not using a function express or function declaration for the callback function then Javascript parses the code and detects a anonymous function and uses iife to invoke the anonymous function.

I cannot find anything on the internet nor an api that describes what is happening behind the scenes, so I ask can somebody explain this to me.

Comment: You can see it being invoked in the code you've posted: `callback(param);`. It's not immediately invoked; if it were, you couldn't then pass it to the other function (unless your IIFE returned a function that was the callback).

Answer (score 0):

IIFE (immeadiately invoked function expression) is just a name coined by the community for this specific construct:

```
  (function() { /*...*/ })()
```

It's a function expression, that is directly followed by a function call to that function. That's it. You don't have an IIFE in your code.

> My question is how does a anonymous function get invoked?

Functions get invoked using a *reference to them*, their name is just a debugging feature (and it's a reference to the function itself inside the functions body). Functions don't need a name:

```
  let test = function /*irrelevant*/ () { };
  let test2 = test; 
  test(); test2();
```

If you use a *function declaration*, the name is not only used as the function name, but also as the name of a variable that references the function:

```
  function named() { }
```

is barely equal to (let's ignore "hoisting" here):

```
  var named = function named() { }
```

If you invoke a function using a function expression as one of it's arguments:

```
   function called(reference) { }

   called(function irrelevant() { })
```

then the function expression gets evaluated, a function gets created, and a reference to it gets passed to the `called` function as an argument, which can then be accessed using the `reference` variable.

Comment: If I understand you correctly the callback(param)  function in function callbackExample is a reference.  So we could substitute the anonymous function  function(param) { console.log(param) } into callback and what is really happening behind the scenes is a function expression being created, since function (param) { console.log(param) } is being assigned to the variable callback and then invoked with (param) so we could write let callback = function(param) { console.log(param) } -- correct? And then we invoke the function expression callback(param).